# Javafx pause between each timeline "cycle"

Tags: java, javafx

At the moment I have a list with images which get displayed for a certain amount of time with a timeline. However I want that after each there is a small pause where no image is displayed? Is there a way to achieve that behavior?

Here is the Code I use so far:

```
ImageView imView = new ImageView();

Duration timeBetweenImages = Duration.millis(10000);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
    Image image = imageList.get(i);
    Duration frameTime = timeBetweenImages.multiply(i);
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(frameTime, e -> imView.setImage(image));
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
}

timeline.play();
```

As for now each picture is displayed 10 seconds. I want that after the each 10 seconds there is a 1 second pause where no image is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imView = new ImageView();

Duration timeBetweenImages = Duration.seconds(11);
Duration pauseTime = Duration.seconds(1);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
    Image image = imageList.get(i);
    Duration frameTime = timeBetweenImages.multiply(i);
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(frameTime, e -> imView.setImage(image));
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);

    Duration pauseFrameTime = timeBetweenImages.multiply(i+1).subtract(pauseTime);
    KeyFrame pauseFrame = new KeyFrame(pauseFrameTime, e -> imView.setImage(null));
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(pauseFrame);
}

timeline.play();
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to combine this with a Transition? I added a RotationTransition to the ImageView which takes 6000 millis, but sadly the timing is off :( I should work like this: Display image and rotate it 360 degree, then 1 second pause and the same with the next images.

Comment: Instead of using a `RotateTransition`, just add key frames to the `Timeline` that use a `new KeyValue(imView.rotateProperty, value)`.

Comment: Does it not work with `RotateTransition`? Because later on I need to make use of the `ParallelTransition` in order to perform multiple transitions at the same time.

Comment: I think it would be hard to do that. A `RotateTransition` represents a single ("one-off") rotation. You want multiple rotations at discrete intervals. I would just add keyframes to the existing timeline.

Comment: Alright thank you very much again, it works with the Rotation like a charm :) This will be the best Diashow.